# Sorted by type in Python

Tags: python, list-comprehension

Say I have a list of objects. Maybe its got some ints, some strings, and some floats. What I'd like to do is sort the list so that all ints are moved to the end of the list but no other types are touches, sort of like this...

```
for idx, el in enumerate(somelist):
    if el.__class__ is int:
        somelist.append(somelist.pop(idx))
```

My question is, is there a way to do this elegantly as a one-liner?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`isinstance(x,int)` will be `True` or `False` so ints will get moved to the end:

```
l = [1.0,"foo",2,3,"bar"]
print(sorted(l, key=lambda x: isinstance(x,int)))
[1.0, 'foo', 'bar', 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 4):

Boolean values are orderable in Python. And sorting is stable.

```
..., key=lambda x: isinstance(x, int), ...
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't care about doing it in place...

```
newlist = [i for i in somelist if not isinstance(x, int)] + [i for i in somelist if isinstance(x, int)]
```

Conveniently, since Python 2.2, sorts are [stable](https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting#Sort_Stability_and_Complex_Sorts), so you can also just do...

```
somelist.sort(key=lambda x: isinstance(x, int))
```

Note however that this does meant that any *subclass* of `int` will also be moved to the end of the list - if you don't want that, you'd want to change the condition to `type(x) is int`).

Comment: Thanks! Forgot you can have more than one comprehension on a line haha

Answer (score 1):

maybe this will be useful in another way:

```
>>> a=[4,'3','2', 6,7,4,'ssa']
>>> for i,j in groupby(sorted(a, key=lambda x: str(type(x))), type):
...     tuple(j)
...
(4, 6, 7, 4)
('3', '2', 'ssa')
>>>
```